# bash: meaningful unique id generation

Tags: linux, bash, pid, uniqueidentifier, unique-id

I am using following command to generate an unique id for my shell script. I want to capture the output in a variable without using any intermediate file on hard disk.

```
    echo `dmidecode –t 4 -s system-uuid`-$$-$BASH_SUBSHELL-$BASHPID-`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M_%S_%N'` | tr '-' '_'
    XXB3A1XX_81XX_4XX2_AXX4_XXXX62820BF_24115_0_8550_201709XX_1446_46_385924883
```

I can use backquote or $() construct but doing so changes the value of $BASH_SUBSHELL and dilutes the value of unique id.

Any solution is welcome which does not use hard disk and does not change the  $BASH_SUBSHELL value while capturing the output in a variable.

note: result in the example is partly obscured with X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `printf` and save the variables in a format string:

```
format="%s-$$-$BASH_SUBSHELL-$BASHPID-%s"
uuid=$(printf "$format" $(dmidecode –t 4 -s system-uuid) $(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M_%S_%N') | tr - _)
```

Then:

```
$ echo "$uuid"
XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX_11764_0_11764_20170912_1906_42_765827138
$ echo `dmidecode –t 4 -s system-uuid`-$$-$BASH_SUBSHELL-$BASHPID-`date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M_%S_%N'` | tr '-' '_'
XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX_11764_0_11865_20170912_1909_28_405748643
```

Comment: we can see $$-$BASH_SUBSHELL-$BASHPID gives 3 unique values with the $BASH_SUBSHELL value retained as 0 in case of direct echo. But with above method we get only 2. The entropy got reduced !!

Comment: @thesudhakar well, that's not a direct echo. You created a fork when you used a pipe. As for entropy, I haven't the faintest idea why you're doing this instead of using something like [`uuidgen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/uuidgen.1.html) or Python to create true UUIDs, so I won't comment.

Comment: I don't see what meaning that thing has, or why it has to have any meaning at all. As for the pipe, when you do `foo | bar`, bash forks off and runs `foo` and `bar` independently. There's no forking involved in the `printf` because there's no pipe and `printf` is a builtin.

Comment: Agreed. 'meaningful' unique id was my requirement as mentioned. Btw, this is also a true unique id. Also for my purpose this method is more guaranteed.

Comment: The uid here has the following meaning: system information, bash shell info, time: these are some of the things we can deduce by looking at it, say, when you are using it as a file name where millions of files can get created across systems simultaneously also under same shell.

Comment: If they're all running in the same shell, only the `date` is really contributing uniqueness, and if you ever run it in a system without support for nanosecond precision in `date`'s output, you're guaranteed collisions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154238/discussion-between-the-sudhakar-and-muru).

Answer (score 1):

There's `uuidgen` for Linux (util-linux) and Mac OS (BSG general commands).

See https://serverfault.com/questions/103359/how-to-create-a-uuid-in-bash